# Failure handler in Google Apps Script receives object different from what is thrown on server side

Tags: google-apps-script

My app sends submitted form data to this server-side function:

```
function processFormData(data)
{
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  // validate data
  var errorObject = {},
      potholeErrors = createErrorObjectFor('pothole'),
      intervalSizeErrors = createErrorObjectFor('intervalSize');
  // make sure numbers are actual numbers and not NaN's.
  if (!validateNumber(data.potholeWidth))
  {
    potholeErrors.messages.push(errorTypes.NOT_A_NUMBER);
    errorObject.potholeWidth = potholeErrors;
  }
  if (!validateNumber(data.intervalSize))
  {
    intervalSizeErrors.messages.push(errorTypes.NOT_A_NUMBER);
    errorObject.intervalSize = intervalSizeErrors;
  }  
  // make sure numbers are within their respective bounds (handled by handleErrors())
  errorObject = handleErrors(data, errorObject);
  // if intervalSize doesn't divide potholeWidth, make it so
  if (data.potholeWidth % data.intervalSize > 0) data.potholeWidth = nextMultiple(data.intervalSize, data.potholeWidth);
  // if there is anything in errorObject, throw it
  if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errorObject).length != 0)
  {
    Logger.log('errorObject == ' + JSON.stringify(errorObject, null, '\t'));
    throw errorObject;
  }
  // createSpreadsheet
  return createSpreadsheet(data.spreadsheet, data.potholeWidth, data.intervalSize);
}
```

which, upon success, does exactly what it's supposed to do. However, when end-user enters any invalid input, the object the server-side throws back is different than the one they end up getting. I tried entering a pothole width that was too small. When I inspected Logger on server-side, I saw this correct output:

[image: what the client side SHOULD be getting....]

however, in the Developer console, I see:

[image: what the client side ACTUALLY gets....]

The code that communicates data to the server looks like:

```
function updateURL(url)
    {
        // activate button
        $('#input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', ''); 
        // change href of #spreadsheetLink
        $('#spreadsheetLink').attr('href', url);
        // unhide the link's container if hidden
        if ($('#spreadsheetLink').parent().hasClass('hidden'))  $('#spreadsheetLink').parent().removeClass('hidden');
        // hide the 'Loading...' element
        if (!$('#loading').hasClass('hidden')) $('#loading').addClass('hidden');
    }

    function emailLink()
    {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() { 
            $('#emailLink').next().text('E-mail message has been sent!');
            $('#emailLink').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }).emailLink($('#spreadsheetLink').attr('href'));
    }

    function handleFails(failData)
    {
        var DEBUG = true;
        if (DEBUG)  console.log('failData == ' + JSON.stringify(failData, null, '\t'));
        // hide 'Loading...' element
        if (!$('#loading').hasClass('hidden')) $('#loading').addClass('hidden');
        // for now, let's ignore any Errors/TypeErrors.
        if ((!failData instanceof Error) && (!failData instanceof TypeError))
        {
            // for now, if there were any errors with any of the fields, simply mark them as .invalid
            if ((failData.potholeWidth) && (failData.potholeWidth.messages.length > 0))
            {
                if (!$('#potholeWidth').hasClass('invalid')) $('#potholeWidth').addClass('invalid');
            }
            if ((failData.intervalSize) && (failData.intervalSize.messages.length > 0))
            {
                if (!$('#intervalSize').hasClass('invalid')) $('#intervalSize').addClass('invalid');
            }
        }
    }

    function submitFormData()
    {
        // hide spreadsheetLink container if not already done, and clear its <span> element if not already clear
        var spreadsheetLinkContainer = $('#spreadsheetLink').parent(),
            spanElement = $('spreadsheetLinkContainer').find('span');
        if (!$(spreadsheetLinkContainer).hasClass('hidden')) $(spreadsheetLinkContainer).addClass('hidden');
        if ($(spanElement).text() != '') $(spanElement).text('');
        // get all data
        var potholeWidth = parseNumberField('potholeWidth'),
            intervalSize = parseNumberField('intervalSize') || defaults.get('intervalSize'),
            concaveEdges = $('input[name="concaveEdges"]').filter(function() { return $(this).prop('checked'); }).next().text() === 'Yes',
            spreadsheetName = parseField('spreadsheetName') || defaults.get('spreadsheetName');
        // make button inactive
        if (($(this).prop('tagName')) && ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'input'))    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        // show "Loading..." element
        if ($('#loading').hasClass('hidden')) $('#loading').removeClass('hidden');
        // submit this data to the server
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateURL).withFailureHandler(handleFails).processFormData(JSON.stringify({
            potholeWidth: potholeWidth,
            intervalSize: intervalSize,
            concaveEdges: concaveEdges,
            spreadsheet : spreadsheetName
        }));
    }
```

and the HTML looks something like this:

```
<form>
        Place straightedge/yardstick along width of pothole such that it points at the corners, <a class="showImage">like this</a>
        <span class="row">
          <label class="firstColumn seventeenTwentieths">Pothole width (in inches): </label>
          <input type="text" class="secondColumn tenth numberField" id="potholeWidth" required />
        </span>
        <span class="rowTight">
          <label class="firstColumn seventeenTwentieths">Interval size (in inches, default 1 inch): </label>
          <input type="text" class="secondColumn tenth numberField" id="intervalSize" value="1" />
        </span>
        <div class="rowTight">
          <label class="firstColumn">Do any of the edges intersect the straightedge/yardstick other than at the corners?</label>
          <div class="secondColumn">
            <span>
              <input type="radio" name="concaveEdges" id="yesConcaveEdges" />
              <label for="yesConcaveEdges">Yes</label>
            </span>
            <br>
            <span>
              <input type="radio" name="concaveEdges" id="noConcaveEdges" checked />
              <label for="noConcaveEdges">No</label>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="rowTight">
          <label class="firstColumn half">Spreadsheet name: </label>
          <input type="text" class="secondColumn nineTwentieths" id="spreadsheetName"/>
        </span>
        <span class="center row">
          <button class="center" id="clearForm">Clear</button>
          <input type="submit" class="center action" value="Create spreadsheet" />
        </span>
      </form>
      <span id="loading" class="row center fullWidth hidden">
      Loading...
      </span>
      <span class="row center fullWidth hidden">
        <a href="#" id="spreadsheetLink">Here is your spreadsheet</a>
        <button id="emailLink">E-mail me the link</button>
        <span></span>
      </span>
```

What is that object the client actually gets and how to make sure that it's getting the object the server actually throws?

Comment: To send data to the server, I used `JSON.stringify()`. I doubt I would have to use that to throw error FROM the server.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

**What I did**

*In code.gs*

Instead of simply `throw errorObject;`, I said `throw JSON.stringify(errorObject);`

*In JavaScript.html file*

in `handleFails()`, I converted the string the server-side threw back into object (`failData = JSON.parse(failData)`) to use it. It outputted it correctly, and all is well.

**What I learned**

**Any** time the server is either giving or receiving data, it **MUST** be in the form of a string! (Use `JSON.stringify()` to make that data a string!)